# Finding word with $ in file using ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm trying to find a word in a file and replacing it using ansible.

The problem is that the word contains the ending regexp special char $ - $wordToFind.

Already tried to escape it using [$]wordToFind or \$wordToFind.
This is the code I'm using:

```
- name: Check if the /pathToFile/file.ext file contains the entry value $wordToFind
shell: "cat /pathToFile/file.ext | grep  \"schwordToFindeme\""
become: yes
become_method: sudo
failed_when: false
register: cat_result
when: condition == "A"

- name: change to newWord if $wordToFind was found
replace:
    dest: //pathToFile/file.ext
    regexp: "$wordToFind"
    replace: "newWord"
    backup: yes
when: cat_result.rc > 0 and condition == "A"
```

Comment: As I can infer, you are trying to make some kind of template system, right? Why don't you simply use [Ansible Templates](https://palletsprojects.com/p/jinja) instead?

Comment: Hi accdias! because the file was not provided by me... It exists and I just need to replace one word!

Comment: It is just a guess and it may sounds dumb but did you try double back slashes as in ```\\$```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change to single quotes. Below one worked for me

```
  - name: change to newWord if $wordToFind was found
    replace:
     dest: //pathToFile/file.ext
     regexp: '\$wordToFind'
     replace: 'newWord'
```

Comment: did you get any error? or may be the problem is with your condition